# I have an error occurring in the machine code for a release that I wrote

Tags: objective-c

[CFNumber release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1fdb96c0

I don't have any NSNumber objects being released in this phase so I am not sure where else this would come from.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

I know there isn't a lot of information to go on, but I tested this code, it worked and I came back today and now it doesn't.  I don't remember changing anything.  If there is more information that could be of some help, please let me know.

### BREAKPOINT ON ZOMBIE

Hope this gives a little more insight on how to solve this.

```
0x33e4c446:  bl     0x33e1ffe8                ; __CFRecordAllocationEvent
0x33e4c44a:  mov    r0, r8
0x33e4c44c:  blx    0x33e88f8c                ; symbol stub for: -[__NSFileSecurity dealloc]
0x33e4c450:  movw   r1, #45522
0x33e4c454:  add.w  r2, r11, #10
0x33e4c458:  movt   r1, #2104
0x33e4c45c:  mov    r3, r0
0x33e4c45e:  add    r1, pc
0x33e4c460:  movs   r0, #3
0x33e4c462:  str    r5, [sp]
0x33e4c464:  bl     0x33e38318                ; CFLog
0x33e4c468:  trap   <--- ....break when zombies are enabled occurs here....
0x33e4c46a:  blx    0x33e89a4c                ; symbol stub for: -[NSOrderedSet intersectsSet:]
0x33e4c46e:  movs   r1, #9
0x33e4c470:  blx    0x33e89b1c                ; symbol stub for: __61-[NSOrderedSet sortedArrayFromRange:options:usingComparator:]_block_invoke_0
0x33e4c474:  movs   r0, #0
0x33e4c476:  b      0x33e4c684                ; ___forwarding___ + 732
0x33e4c478:  movw   r0, #52812
0x33e4c47c:  movt   r0, #2103
0x33e4c480:  add    r0, pc
0x33e4c482:  ldr    r6, [r0]
0x33e4c484:  mov    r0, r4
0x33e4c486:  mov    r1, r6
0x33e4c488:  blx    0x33e88d4c                ; symbol stub for: -[NSCache countLimit]
0x33e4c48c:  ldr.w  r10, [sp, #12]
0x33e4c490:  tst.w  r0, #255
0x33e4c494:  bne    0x33e4c4d2                ; ___forwarding___ + 298
0x33e4c496:  mov    r0, r4
0x33e4c498:  blx    0x33e88d2c                ; symbol stub for: __NSCheckReentrancy
0x33e4c49c:  mov    r6, r0
0x33e4c49e:  mov    r0, r5
0x33e4c4a0:  blx    0x33e88f4c                ; symbol stub for: -[NSMutableOrderedSet setObject:]
0x33e4c4a4:  mov    r4, r0
0x33e4c4a6:  cbnz   r6, 0x33e4c4bc            ; ___forwarding___ + 276
0x33e4c4a8:  mov    r0, r5
0x33e4c4aa:  blx    0x33e88f4c                ; symbol stub for: -[NSMutableOrderedSet setObject:]
```

Comment: When messages are sent to deallocated objects often unexpected behavior appears. It is not uncommon to see irregular target objects in the message log. Product Anaylze will probably help you find the problem.

Comment: Show the code, there will be probably a NSNumber which receives a release message while it's already deallocated.

Comment: You've got a double release of an NSNumber object.  It may not be you that's releasing it -- it could be an NSNumber in an NSArray, eg, and the array's being released.  But one way or another it's very probably your "fault" that it's being released twice.